# Webpack, Why do we need hash to cache files effectively?

Tags: webpack, browser-cache

From https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html,

The first paragraph says

> To effectively cache your files, they should have a hash or version in
>   their URL.

What is the purpose of hash/version in the URL that enables browser to cache files long term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it's not a good idea to cache files that could change in the near future for a longer period as your clients possibly don't load the latest version of these files. So caching your `bundle.js` could lead to the problem that after an update of your code, the browser still loads your old `bundle.js` due to some caching settings.

A good way to solve this (which is easy to use when using webpack) is to hash the resulting bundle and append this hash to the file name. So your first version is called `bundle.ad736defe.js` and after any modification this name will also change, for example to `bundle.dffe3983.js`. Having this in place, you can cache these files forever as every change to your code will result in a new file name and thus the client will use the cached one as long as the exact same file is referenced in your index.html and it will download the new version as soon as you changed anything that affects the bundle's content.

Webpack has that feature built in which is super easy to activate by providing an output file name containing the `[hash]` pattern.

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  publicPath: "/",
  filename: "bundle-[hash].js"
}
```

This will put your hashed bundle into `dist/bundle.<calculated_hash>.js`.

As you don't know the filename beforehand, you can make use of the great [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) that will automatically insert the script tags with the correct hashes for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've been deploying JS files, without `chunkhash`, so I guess its pretty risky. What if my `bundle.js` file size changed? Can the browser detect that the file had changed ,and it should download a new version?

Comment: It's only risky if you configured some longer caching settings that the server tells the browser when delivering the files. With such settings the browser will no longer attempt to download a file with the same name. So it will not even ask the server if the file size has changed. If you use hashing and the file size changes, you will get a new hash. No problem to introduce this later on after having started without hashing.